# How can I perform the Count function with a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my database setup to allow a user to "Like" or "Dislike" a post. If it is liked, the column isliked = true, false otherwise (null if nothing.)

The problem is, I am trying to create a view that shows all Posts, and also shows a column with how many 'likes' and 'dislikes' each post has. Here is my SQL; I'm not sure where to go from here. It's been a while since I've worked with SQL and everything I've tried so far has not given me what I want.

Perhaps my DB isn't setup properly for this. Here is the SQL:

```
Select trippin.AccountData.username, trippin.PostData.posttext, 

trippin.CategoryData.categoryname, Count(trippin.LikesDislikesData.liked)

as TimesLiked from trippin.PostData

inner join trippin.AccountData on trippin.PostData.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id
inner join trippin.CategoryData on trippin.CategoryData.id = trippin.PostData.categoryid
full outer join trippin.LikesDislikesData on trippin.LikesDislikesData.postid =
trippin.PostData.id

full outer join trippin.LikesDislikesData likes2 on trippin.LikesDislikesData.accountid = 

trippin.AccountData.id
Group By (trippin.AccountData.username), (trippin.PostData.posttext), (trippin.categorydata.categoryname);
```

Here's my table setup (I've only included relevant columns):

```
LikesDislikesData
isliked(bit) || accountid(string) || postid(string

PostData
id(string) || posttext || accountid(string)

AccountData
id(string) || username(string)

CategoryData
categoryname(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1: FULL OUTER JOIN versus LEFT OUTER JOIN. Full outer joins are seldom what you want, it means you want all data specified on the "left" and all data specified on the "right", that are matched and unmatched.  What you want is all the PostData on the "left" and any matching Likes data on the "right". If some right hand side rows don't match something on the left, then you *don't care* about it. Almost always work from left to right and join results that are relevant.

Problem 2: table alias. Where ever you alias a table name - such as Likes2 - then every instance of that table within the query needs to use that alias. Straight after you declare the alias Likes2, your join condition refers back to trippin.LikesDislikesData, which is the first instance of the table.  Given the second one in joining on a different field I suspect that the postid and accountid are being matched on the same row, therefore it should be AND together, not a separate table instance. EDIT reading your schema closer, it seems this wouldn't be needed at all.

Problem 3: to solve you Counts problem separate them using CASE statements.  Count will add the number of non NULL values returned for each CASE. If the likes.liked = 1, then return 1 otherwise return NULL. The NULL will be returned if the columns contains a 0 or a NULL.

```
SELECT trippin.PostData.Id, trippin.AccountData.username, trippin.PostData.posttext,     
    trippin.CategoryData.categoryname, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN likes.liked = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TimesLiked, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN likes.liked = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TimesDisLiked 
FROM trippin.PostData    
INNER JOIN trippin.AccountData ON trippin.PostData.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id
INNER JOIN trippin.CategoryData ON trippin.CategoryData.id = trippin.PostData.categoryid
LEFT OUTER JOIN trippin.LikesDislikesData likes ON likes.postid = trippin.PostData.id
                    -- remove                      AND likes.accountid = trippin.AccountData.id

GROUP BY trippin.PostData.Id, (trippin.AccountData.username), (trippin.PostData.posttext), (trippin.categorydata.categoryname);
```

Then "hide" the PostId column in the User Interface.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the insight. I haven't used SQL since my 1.5 years ago...took one course on it. Anyway, the SQL code does not work unless I remove the Count functions. "Incorrect syntax near =" I have been trying to figure out why, but to no avail. Also, the column likes.liked holds 'true' and 'false' as a bit type; although I believe changing it to use 0 and 1 is a better idea.

Comment: @user3007447 sorry forgot the WHEN and END key words - see edit. My bad

Comment: The bit column does hold 1 (= true) & 0 (= false) inside the database. Some query tools will display you the representation (ie true/false) rather than the raw data (1/0).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. -- I do have one more question if you're willing? Not sure if this is allowed...

I had two rows of data with the same "PostText", accountid and categoryid, but different PostID -- this SQL statement only selected one of the two posts that had the same text. Any idea?

Comment: If they were created by the same user as well, then they would be grouped together, because we have posttext in the GROUP BY, not postid.  Changing it to GROUP BY PostId may work as there should be a one-to-one between the other fields in the Select (username, posttext and categoryname) and the PostId. If that doesn't work straight up, then add PostId in front of the other fields, and include it in the select as well, that will fix it.

Comment: Hm. Well I don't want to include the ID in my select statement but changing it to group by ID without selecting it doesn't work. Your second option worked and I am very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: This answer actually does not work. I needed to remove the link between likes.accountid and accountdata.id -- and now the "count" is showing up as "1" for each post that has 0 likes.

Comment: @user3007447 you are saying it did work. Then you made a change and now it doesn't work.

Comment: In order for this to work, I had to remove the "and likes.accountid = accountdata.id" and change Count() to Sum() and to prevent getting a warning, change "else null" to "else 0". I originally said it worked because I had limited sample data which matched up to what was being shown to me. I added more data and then realized this wasn't working the original way.

Comment: @user3007447. No problems. I originally commented out the "and likes.accountid = accountdata.id", because I thought they may be incorrect.  I also toyed with using SUM instead of COUNT, but without having data to test against, I assumed that they would produce the same result in this context.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting `Count(trippin.LikesDislikesData.liked)` you could put in a select statement:

```
Select AccountData.username, PostData.posttext, CategoryData.categoryname, 
  (select Count(*) 
   from LikesDislikesData as likes2 
   where likes2.postid = postdata.id
   and  likes2.liked = 'like' ) as TimesLiked 
from PostData 
inner join AccountData on PostData.accountid = AccountData.id
inner join CategoryData on CategoryData.id = PostData.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorksDW2008R2
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

/*
Default
*/
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO

BEGIN TRAN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#LikesDislikesData') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #LikesDislikesData
END

CREATE TABLE #LikesDislikesData(
       isLiked      bit
      ,accountid    VARCHAR(50)
      ,postid       VARCHAR(50)
     );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#PostData') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #PostData
END

CREATE TABLE #PostData(
      postid    INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
     ,accountid VARCHAR(50)
     ,posttext  VARCHAR(50)
     );


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#AccountData') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #AccountData
END

CREATE TABLE #AccountData(
       accountid    INT
      ,username VARCHAR(50)
     );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#CategoryData') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CategoryData
END

CREATE TABLE #CategoryData(
      categoryname  VARCHAR(50)
     );

INSERT INTO #AccountData VALUES ('1', 'user1')       
INSERT INTO #PostData VALUES('1','this is a post')
INSERT INTO #LikesDislikesData (isLiked ,accountid, postid)
SELECT '1', P.accountid, P.postid
FROM #PostData P
WHERE P.posttext = 'this is a post'

SELECT *
FROM    #PostData

SELECT *
FROM    #LikesDislikesData

SELECT *
FROM #AccountData


SELECT  COUNT(L.isLiked) 'Likes'
        ,P.posttext
        ,A.username                         
FROM #PostData P
JOIN #LikesDislikesData L 
ON P.accountid = L.accountid
AND L.IsLiked = 1
JOIN #AccountData A
ON P.accountid = A.accountid
GROUP BY P.posttext, A.username



SELECT X.likes, Y.dislikes
FROM (
        (SELECT COUNT(isliked)as 'likes', accountid
        FROM #LikesDislikesData 
        WHERE isLiked = 1
        GROUP BY accountid
         ) X
        JOIN
        (SELECT COUNT(isliked)as 'dislikes', accountid
        FROM #LikesDislikesData 
        WHERE isLiked = 0
        GROUP BY accountid) Y
        ON x.accountid = y.accountid)

IF (XACT_STATE() = 1 AND ERROR_STATE() = 0)
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN
END
ELSE IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you think about the solution? We create a new table SummaryReport(PostID,AccountID,NumberOfLikedTime,NumberOfDislikedTimes).

An user clicks on LIKE or DISLIKE button we update the table. After that, you can query as you desire. Another advantage, the table can be served reporting purpose.

Comment: I don't believe this solution would work; If I use that setup, it would show me the AccountID of the user that created the post; I want the AccountID of the user that LIKED/DISLIKED the post.
Thank you though!

Comment: this can be determined better through summary functions such as COUNT. Maintaining summary tables is more expensive in most instances, until you start separating information into more finite groups, such as hourly or daily and then performing additional tasks, such as trending etc. When you go to this level, then summary tables begin to become more workable, but not in this straight forward instance.